# MS Access - Using SumOfValue from one Query in another Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum

I have a Query in MS Access that has the following information:

- NO (Unique Identifier)
- Make
- Model

In another Query, it has the same REF numbers numerous times, with different Values and Acct so I just want the Sum of Value for each REF. I have the following information:

- REF
- Acct
- Sum of Value (It gets the sum of the Value field by using REF as the Identifier)

How can I get the SumofValue field from Query2 as a column in Query1 when REF matches NO?  So that the query shows the SumValue for each NO.

I added the 2 queries to the Query Builder, and created a relationship between REF and NO.  I then added the SumOfValue field and NO field to the query but Type Mismatch error occurs.

Comment: the next step is to put that code here - then we can see what you have / have not done, then answering is easy.

Comment: If you can show the SQL for each of the two queries, we can help you construct a new query all together that will not need the two existing queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, then all you need to do is JOIN them together:

```
SELECT t1.NO, t1.Make, t1.Model, t2.SumValue 
FROM MyQueryName1 AS t1
INNER JOIN MyQueryName2 AS t2 ON t1.NO = t2.REF
```

If you are getting a type mismatch error, then make sure that `NO` and `REF` are the same date type.  You can use a function in the join to convert the data type.  For instance, if `REF was Text and`NO` was a Long Integer, you could use:

```
INNER JOIN MyQueryName2 AS t2 ON t1.NO = CLong(t2.REF)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used the function to change the data type (it is a linked table so I couldn't do this within Table Designer) which helped me achieve what I wanted. Many thanks!